# Элемент за пределами overflow

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

У меня есть список с фикс. высотой и прокруткой, с элементами label. Кликая на элемент label, возле элемента по которому кликнули появляется кнопка.

Мне нужно чтобы эта кнопка была за пределами списка, но напротив элемента.

Нужно какое-то решение, подойдут даже костыли :(

Вот, что нужно:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот мой код:

```css
.check {
  width: 150px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

.check label {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
}

.box-button {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  right: -10px;
  top: 0;
  background-color: #fc0;
  box-shadow: 1.4px 1.4px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.35);
  border: none;
  color: #424242;
  padding: 0 5px;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 400;
  line-height: 28px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="check">
  <label for="check-1">
                    <input id="check-1" class="element-checkbox" name="check-1" value="Motul" type="checkbox">
                    <span>Motul</span>
                   </label>
  <label for="check-2">
                    <input id="check-2" class="element-checkbox" name="check-2" value="Motul" type="checkbox">
                    <span>Motul</span>
                   </label>
  <label for="check-3">
                    <input id="check-3" class="element-checkbox" name="check-3" value="Motul" type="checkbox">
                    <span>Motul</span>
                   </label>
  <label for="check-4">
                    <input id="check-4" class="element-checkbox" name="check-4" value="Motul" type="checkbox">
                    <span>Motul</span>
                   </label>
  <label for="check-5">
                    <input id="check-5" class="element-checkbox" name="check-5" value="Motul" type="checkbox">
                    <span>Motul</span>
                   </label>
  <label for="check-6">
                    <input id="check-6" class="element-checkbox" name="check-6" value="Motul" type="checkbox">
                    <span>Motul</span>
                   </label>
  <button class="box-button">Показать</button>
</div>
<div class="check">
  <label for="check-7">
                    <input id="check-7" class="element-checkbox" name="check-7" value="Motul" type="checkbox">
                    <span>Motul</span>
                   </label>
  <label for="check-8">
                    <input id="check-8" class="element-checkbox" name="check-8" value="Motul" type="checkbox">
                    <span>Motul</span>
                   </label>
  <label for="check-9">
                    <input id="check-9" class="element-checkbox" name="check-9" value="Motul" type="checkbox">
                    <span>Motul</span>
                   </label>
  <label for="check-10">
                    <input id="check-10" class="element-checkbox" name="check-10" value="Motul" type="checkbox">
                    <span>Motul</span>
                   </label>
  <label for="check-11">
                    <input id="check-11" class="element-checkbox" name="check-11" value="Motul" type="checkbox">
                    <span>Motul</span>
                   </label>
  <label for="check-12">
                    <input id="check-12" class="element-checkbox" name="check-12" value="Motul" type="checkbox">
                    <span>Motul</span>
                   </label>
  <button class="box-button">Показать</button>
</div>
<script>
  $(".check label").click(function() {
 var $parentBox = $(this).closest('.check');
  $('.box-button', $parentBox).show();
  clearTimeout($parentBox.data('timeout'));
  $parentBox.data('timeout', setTimeout(function() {
    $('.box-button', $parentBox).hide();
  }, 4000));
  $('.box-button', $parentBox).appendTo(this);
  });
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Решение: кнопка остается одна и только одна, выносится в самый низ. При клике вычисляется смещение сверху и слева и устанавливается это смещение кнопке.

```js
var showBtn = $('.box-button');
var checkBlock = $('.check');
var addOffset = 15;
$(".check label").click(function() {

  var offsetTop = $(this).offset().top - 5;
  var offsetLeft = checkBlock.offset().left + checkBlock.width() + addOffset;
  showBtn.offset({top: offsetTop, left: offsetLeft});
  showBtn.show();

  clearTimeout($(showBtn).data('timer'));
  $(showBtn).data('timer', setTimeout(function() {
    showBtn.offset({top: 0, left: 0});
    showBtn.hide();
  }, 4000));
});
```

```css
.check {
  width: 150px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

.check label {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
}

.box-button {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  right: -10px;
  top: 0;
  background-color: #fc0;
  box-shadow: 1.4px 1.4px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.35);
  border: none;
  color: #424242;
  padding: 0 5px;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 400;
  line-height: 28px;
}

.box-button::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: -12px;
  top: -1px;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-top: 15px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 15px solid transparent;
  border-right: 15px solid #fc0;
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="check">
  <label for="check-1">
    <input id="check-1" class="element-checkbox" name="check-1" value="Motul" type="checkbox">
    <span>Motul</span>
    </label>
  <label for="check-2">
    <input id="check-2" class="element-checkbox" name="check-2" value="Motul" type="checkbox">
    <span>Motul</span>
    </label>
  <label for="check-3">
    <input id="check-3" class="element-checkbox" name="check-3" value="Motul" type="checkbox">
    <span>Motul</span>
    </label>
  <label for="check-4">
    <input id="check-4" class="element-checkbox" name="check-4" value="Motul" type="checkbox">
    <span>Motul</span>
    </label>
  <label for="check-5">
    <input id="check-5" class="element-checkbox" name="check-5" value="Motul" type="checkbox">
    <span>Motul</span>
    </label>
  <label for="check-6">
    <input id="check-6" class="element-checkbox" name="check-6" value="Motul" type="checkbox">
    <span>Motul</span>
    </label>
</div>
<div class="check">
  <label for="check-7">
    <input id="check-7" class="element-checkbox" name="check-7" value="Motul" type="checkbox">
    <span>Motul</span>
    </label>
  <label for="check-8">
    <input id="check-8" class="element-checkbox" name="check-8" value="Motul" type="checkbox">
    <span>Motul</span>
    </label>
  <label for="check-9">
    <input id="check-9" class="element-checkbox" name="check-9" value="Motul" type="checkbox">
    <span>Motul</span>
    </label>
  <label for="check-10">
    <input id="check-10" class="element-checkbox" name="check-10" value="Motul" type="checkbox">
    <span>Motul</span>
    </label>
  <label for="check-11">
    <input id="check-11" class="element-checkbox" name="check-11" value="Motul" type="checkbox">
    <span>Motul</span>
    </label>
  <label for="check-12">
    <input id="check-12" class="element-checkbox" name="check-12" value="Motul" type="checkbox">
    <span>Motul</span>
    </label>
</div>
<button class="box-button">Показать</button>
```

Так как хотелось костылей, то оставлю как ДЗ догадаться почему написано `$(this).offset().top - 5;` и `var addOffset = 15;` и избавиться от магических чисел ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Показать что-либо за пределами блока с `overflow: hidden` нет возможности, потому вам надо вынести вашу кнопку «Показать» за пределы блока. По клику определять относительные координаты (`.position().top`) элемента и присваивать их свойству `top` вашей кнопке.

```js
$(function() {
  $('label').click(function() {
    var y = $(this).position().top;
    
    $('.show').css('top', y + 'px');
  });
});
```

```css
.wrapper {
  position: absolute;
}

.scrollable {
  overflow-y: auto;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  border: 1px solid;
}

ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
}

li {
  padding: 5px;
}

.show {
  position: absolute;
  top: -100px;
  left: 220px;
  text-decoration: none;
  border: 1px solid;
  padding: 5px 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class=wrapper>
  <div class=scrollable>
    <ul>
      <li><label><input type=checkbox>Product</label>
      <li><label><input type=checkbox>Product</label>
      <li><label><input type=checkbox>Product</label>
      <li><label><input type=checkbox>Product</label>
      <li><label><input type=checkbox>Product</label>
      <li><label><input type=checkbox>Product</label>
      <li><label><input type=checkbox>Product</label>
      <li><label><input type=checkbox>Product</label>
      <li><label><input type=checkbox>Product</label>
      <li><label><input type=checkbox>Product</label>
      <li><label><input type=checkbox>Product</label>
      <li><label><input type=checkbox>Product</label>
      <li><label><input type=checkbox>Product</label>
      <li><label><input type=checkbox>Product</label>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>

<a href="#" class="show">Show</a>
```